# Links to social media in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, rails-admin

So I'm building one website in rails and I'm using Rails admin as administration for that site. 
I would like to have in one of the section something like a bio of a person and at the bottom of the bio I want icons of social media with links for that person social media. It will be that way for each person I had to the site. Can I make this in rails? How?
Anyone knows how I can had links to images in Rails admin?

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem paperclip and rails admin will automatically convert those picture fields to small previews and will also allow you to upload the images using an automatically generated widget.